# HTML: center <p> between two floating <img>

Tags: html, css, css-float

The following code doesn't place the `<p>` text in the center, but rather at about ~60/70 % of the width. What's happening in the background / why is this not working?

```
<div>
<img src="logo.jpg" style="float: left;">
<p style="text-align: center;"> hello world </p>
<img src="logo2.jpg" style="float: right;">
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide working code.

Comment: it depends on your image size and css, so please provide.

Comment: @Doggo Probably because it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Maharkus my bad :D

Comment: @Doggo All good :)

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of flexbox to align items as needed, read the comments on each of its uses and try to tweak it around :)

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;  /*Generates a flexbox layout with default flex direction as row */
  width: 100%; /* Not really required */
  align-items: center; /*Aligns contents vertically */
  justify-content: space-between; /*Aligns contents horizontally */
  text-align: center; /*Aligns further text in the center */
  /* flex-direction:row; By default its row, you can change to column for vertical alignment */
  /* flex-flow:row wrap; To wrap items in other row when no more can be fit in the same row*/
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" >
  <p > hello world </p>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" >
</div>
```

Comment: Beat me to it :) One thing: maybe space-between fits more to what OP wants

Comment: @Maharkus Oh, yeah I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following **x3** approaches, as demonstrated in the code snippet embedded below:

1. Move `p` element below floated elements
   circumvent the *step-down effect* caused by floated elements
2. Nest `img` elements within the `p` element
   Allow the paragraph tag to occupy the full available width with nested floated elements
3. Nest *absolutely positioned* `img` elements within the `p` element
   Remove the nested images from the normal document flow

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

*Note: this snippet is purely intended to demonstrate the aforementioned methods, liberties have been taken in the assumption of images sizes.*

```css
code {
    background: #dadada;
    padding: 3px;
}

* {
    font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<h3>1) Move <code>p</code> element below floated elements</h3>
<div>
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" style="float: left;">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" style="float: right;">
  <p style="text-align: center;"> hello world </p>
</div>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<h3>2) Nest <code>img</code> elements within the <code>p</code> element</h3>
<div>
  <p style="text-align: center;">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" style="float: left;"> 
    hello world 
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" style="float: right;">
  </p>
</div>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<h3>3) Nest <em>absolutely positioned</em> <code>img</code> elements within the <code>p</code> element</h3>
<div>
  <p style="text-align: center; position: relative;">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" style="position: absolute; left: 0;"> 
    hello world 
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" style="position: absolute; right: 0;">
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: That's neat and detailed haha +1

Answer (score 0):

Try using flexbox, it solves everything.

For real though, `justify-content: space-between` on the parent can be used to place the content as you want to.

```css
div {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" style="float: left;">
<p style="text-align: center;"> hello world </p>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" style="float: right;">
</div>
```